# Equivalent of Mathematica Table in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, vectorization, wolfram-mathematica

How to vectorize the following code in Matlab?

```
m = meshgrid(1:n);
for i = 1:n
    for j = 1:n
        m(i,j) = max(i,j);
    end
end
```

Another way to think of the question would be: how to implement the Mathematica command:

```
Table[Max[i,j],{i,1,n},{j,1,n}]:
```

in Matlab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With implicit expansion,

```matlab
m = max([1:n].',[1:n]);
```

For `n = 5`:

```
m =

   1   2   3   4   5
   2   2   3   4   5
   3   3   3   4   5
   4   4   4   4   5
   5   5   5   5   5
```

Comment: That's quite neat. I actually did not know about this. Somehow I am always stuck into thinking of "proper" algebraic operations, so I always forget about implicit expansion.